# Why is routerLink mandatory in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Big fan of Angular, I followed Angular2 official documentation about routing (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html) to build my first test app and fell into following incomprehensible behavior.

My template part in AppComponent looks like:

```
template: `


<h1>Component Router</h1>
  <nav>
    <a [routerLink]="['/crisis-center']">Crisis Center</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['/heroes']">Heroes</a>
  </nav>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`,
```

It works. I can access /crisis-center or /heroes by directly entering the urls in my browser or by clicking on the defined links generated by routerLink directive.

Now, I don't want anymore to display the navigation menu but I want my app to navigate to /crisis-center or /heroes by entering the urls directly in the browser bar, so I removed the nav block and my template looks now like:

```
template: `
  <h1>Component Router</h1>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
`,
```

However, this new version does not display components specific content and only display the parent template part.
*Note: when keeping only one routerLink directive, both components heroes and crisis-center can be navigated to.*

The only workaround I found was applying a display:none to my nav tag.

Why is the directive **routerLink** mandatory to have the routing working? For me, it was just a directive that generates the urls and does not influence the routing process...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue. You can alternatively inject the router to your root component

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(router Router){}
}
```

Without one of these workarounds the router is not instantiated and accordingly does nothing.

Comment: Missed this one. Thanks a lot!